# Cómo se puede ejecutar código de C++ en la GPU

Tags: c++, gpu

Cómo hacer para que una función se ejecute en la GPU, y qué es lo que hace que dicha función se ejecute en la GPU?

Por ejemplo como haría para que la función 'test()' se ejecute en la GPU en el siguiente código de ejemplo:

```
    #include <ctime>
    #include <chrono>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    int test() { 
        int ex = 0;
            auto strt = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
          while (true) {
            
                int time = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(strt - chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()).count();
                if ( time > 100000) {
                     
                    return ex;
                }
                ex++;
            }
            auto end = chrono::system_clock::now();
         
    }
    int main()
    {
        cout << "Número de ejecuciones: " << test();
    }
```

Comment: Esencialmente usas librerías adicionales que te den acceso a las instrucciones de la GPU y te permitan interactuar con ella. Algo como [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-zone)

Comment: Por otro lado piensa que no todo lo que se ejecute en la GPU va a ir más rápido que si se ejecuta en el micro. La GPU es especialmente buena tratando con matrices y solo cuando el volumen de información es lo suficientemente grande como para compensar el tiempo que se tarda en subir todos los datos a la memoria de la GPU. No termino de ver qué mejora esperas obtener al ejecutar ese código (o uno similar) en la GPU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las GPUs tienen sus propios lenguajes de programacion. No son C++.

Algunos son exclusios de una marca, p.e. lenguaje CUDA de NVIDIA.

Otros son standard para varias marcas, p.e. OpenCL.

Puedes ver este enlace:

[CUDA vs OpenCL](https://www.incredibuild.com/blog/cuda-vs-opencl-which-to-use-for-gpu-programming)